# How to connect to FTPS (FTP Tls) server in python

Tags: python, ssl, ftp, ftps

how can I connect to an FTPS server and download files in it?
Currently I am using the following code to retrieve some files in FTPS Server built with Docker.

```
import ftplib
import os
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

def connect(host, port, user, password):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS()
    ftp.debugging = 2
    ftp.connect(host, port)
    ftp.login(user, password)
    return ftp


def retrieveFileList(ftp, ftp_paths, fileType, destinationPath, date):
    total_files = []
    timestamps = []
    for path in ftp_paths:
        currentPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(destinationPath)
        ftp.cwd(path)
        files = ftp.nlst('*'+ fileType)
        for file in files:
            timestamp = ftp.voidcmd("MDTM " + file)[4:].strip()
            time = parser.parse(timestamp)
            parsed_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m")
            timestamps.append(parsed_time)
            if not date > parsed_time:
                total_files.append(file)
                with open(file, 'wb') as f:
                    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, f.write)
        os.chdir(currentPath)
    max_timestamp = max(timestamps)
    return total_files, max_timestamp
```

My questions are the following:

1. Do I have to verify server certificate?
2. Do I have to create an SSL context and pass it as parameter in FTP_TLS()
3. Do I need a certificate (client certificate) in order to connect to the server?

I cannot find any complete code example or explanation online, can anyone help me?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS) suggests you must call `prot_p` to switch to TLS. So your `connect()` function should look like:

```
def connect(host, port, user, password):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS()
    ftp.debugging = 2
    ftp.connect(host, port)
    ftp.prot_p()
    ftp.login(user, password)
    return ftp
```

The documentation doesn't say SSL context is required. The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2a721258a199e9bcdcee2069719ad9c8f8c0d030/Lib/ftplib.py#L714-L715) shows the same. That means a default context will be used. You would probably need a custom context if the server certificate is not publicly trusted. If the server is using a self-signed certificate or a certificate signed by an internal CA, you would probably need a custom context.

As for client certificate, that depends on your specific server requirements.